# Django: When using register.inclusion_tag() where/what order is the template searched for?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

When using the `register.inclusion_tag()` shortcut on a Custom Template Tag, assuming you define the template as `'some_fragment.html'`, in what directories/order does Django try to find that template?

Assume as many 'defaults' as is reasonable.

The Custom Template Tag portion of the documentation doesn't list anything specific, except that the template there is one that is defined by the template tag author, *not* the designer.

I read that and assume that it might look in your custom template tags directory first, but haven't tried it yet, but I have a feeling that it does the 'usual defaults' for templates, and nothing magical or special... but it *is* pony powered, so I had to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows exactly the same rules [as for any other template](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates). That is, it will use the directories specified in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting in order - then, depending on the contents of your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting, will also look in `templates` subdirectories under each of your apps. It won't ever look in the templatetags directory itself.